# Deploy 2 different prod servers with 2 different env vars in NextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, deployment

In my Next.js project, I'm trying to deploy a new version of the app to a development server that uses environment variables from .env.development. Here's the process that we follow:

1. Develop the feature
2. Test locally using next dev
3. Deploy to a **dev server** (replica of prod using dev env vars)
4. Deploy to a prod server using next build && next export && next start

My problem is with step 3, next build and next start use the `.env.production` environment variables, which is not what we want for the dev server.

I'm aware that Next.js only has three environments - production, development, and test - and that `.env.development` is used by next dev and `.env.production` is used by next start.

How can I deploy the project to the **dev server** using the `.env.development` environment variables? I've tried setting the NODE_ENV environment variable to development when running next build and next start, but it still uses the `.env.production` environment variables.

Here is what I've tried

`package.json`

````
"scripts": {
  "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development next build && next export",
  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development next start"
}```
````

I can't change the process, so I need to figure out a solution, if there is no out of the box solution, I'll change the deployment pipeline to copy the `.env.development` over the `.env.production`, but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js can do a `production` build and a `development` build, which are very different "modes", e.g. the `development` build includes a lot of debug information and hot-reloading.

What you actually need is a second Next.js `production` build (i.e. using `.env.production`), even if you are not deploying it to your "production server" but to a different server, which you happen to call "development server" (and with a different environment).

As you could theoretically want to have an arbitrary amount of different environments and/or servers, this is outside of what Next.js would handle.

You need to manage 2 different `.env.production` files yourself, using e.g. deployment scripts or server configurations.